# How to change date format in ngbDatepicker input field in angular bootstrap?

Tags: angular, date, date-formatting, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

HTML:-

```
      <li><span class="float-left label">Date of birth</span>
        <div class="float-right fill-text position-relative edit-calender">
          <input type="text" (click)="d.toggle()" class="edit-field"
            [outsideDays]="'collapsed'" id="datePicker" ngbDatepicker formControlName="dob" #d="ngbDatepicker" [minDate]="minDate"
            [maxDate]="maxDate" readonly>
          <span class="calendar" id="calIcon" (click)="waitAndToggle();"><i id="calIcon" class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
          <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.get('dob').hasError('required')
                && ( form.get('dob').touched || formSubmitAttempt)">
            {{ 'Validations.dob' | translate }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Now when I select some date, it set as YYYY-MM-DD format but I need to change in other format (MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYY).
Check its node_modules folder but didn't git any solution for the same.

I checked the gist https://gist.github.com/nrobinaubertin/61ff1c3db355c74f4e56f485b566ab22 but this didn't set the value in input field as DD-MM-YYYY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a class that extends a NbgDateParserFormat you must include it in app.module in providers,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: DateParserFormatter },
    ...

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: This works in your link. Let me implement in my code

Comment: Also work in mine too but I m surprised to see we need to do lots of changes for change only format

Comment: Really it's only write a DateParserFormatter (the example is more complex because I wanted the class was "parametrizable", but it's only create two functions: "parse" and "format")

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this, I finally got it working in my app. :)

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution would be to change

> ngb-date-parser-formatter.js

from the code below you will get **DD-MM-YYYY** **Date format** in input filed.

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
import { padNumber, toInteger, isNumber } from '../util/util';
/**
 * Abstract type serving as a DI token for the service parsing and formatting dates for the NgbInputDatepicker
 * directive. A default implementation using the ISO 8601 format is provided, but you can provide another implementation
 * to use an alternative format.
 */
var NgbDateParserFormatter = (function () {
    function NgbDateParserFormatter() {
    }
    return NgbDateParserFormatter;
}());
export { NgbDateParserFormatter };
var NgbDateISOParserFormatter = (function (_super) {
    __extends(NgbDateISOParserFormatter, _super);
    function NgbDateISOParserFormatter() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    NgbDateISOParserFormatter.prototype.parse = function (value) {
        if (value) {
            var dateParts = value.trim().split('-');
            if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
                return { year: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null, day: null };
            }
            else if (dateParts.length === 2 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
                return { year: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]), day: null };
            }
            else if (dateParts.length === 3 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1]) && isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
                return { year: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]), day: toInteger(dateParts[2]) };
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
    NgbDateISOParserFormatter.prototype.format = function (date) {
        return date ?
        (isNumber(date.day) ? padNumber(date.day) : '')+"-"+ (isNumber(date.month) ? padNumber(date.month) : '') +"-"+ date.year:'';
    };
    return NgbDateISOParserFormatter;
}(NgbDateParserFormatter));
export { NgbDateISOParserFormatter };
//# sourceMappingURL=ngb-date-parser-formatter.js.map
```